# Java data structure of 500 million (double) values?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, heap-dump

I am generating random edges for a complete graph with 32678 Vertices. So, 500 million + values.

I am using a HashMap to using the edges as key and the random edge weight as the value. I keep encountering:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>     at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:430)     at
>   pa1.Graph.(Graph.java:60)   at pa1.Main.main(Main.java:19)

This graph will then be used to construct a Minimum Spanning Tree.

Any ideas on a better data-structure or approach?

I know there are overrides to allocate more memory, but I would prefer a solution that works as-is.

Comment: anything stopping you from using a database?

Comment: I've thought of that-- it is a HW Problem, and I don't think that a DB is the correct route. Just feel like I may be missing something here...

Comment: umm, correct me if I'm wrong, but `500 000 000 * 32 bits = 1.86264515 gigabytes` default Xmx for java is no more than 128mb.

Comment: Sounds like you need to consider adjacency matrix for such a densely populated graph, rather than HashMap. Although that's still several GB for the one map.

Comment: (Also note that a double is 64 bits, not 32. So that'd be 64 * 32768 * 32768 = 68719476736 bits = 8 589 934 592 bytes (8.5 GB). A hash table is going to be at least 20% worse than this, and probably more)

Comment: @BillyONeal That's pretty huge! Like I mentioned, this is a HW problem-- we generate (large) complete graphs and then find the Minimum Spanning Tree. It is obviously do-able, just having trouble getting started!

Comment: @quannabe: You can generate large graphs without making them fully connected.

Comment: @BillyONeal my mistake, I should have been more clear-- they are required to be complete graphs with 32678 vertices :)

Comment: @BillyONeal: It's presumably an undirected graph, so we'd be looking at (slightly under) 4GiB and not 8GiB.

Comment: @Nabb: That's an interesting presumption. (Yes, MST is usually an undirected thing; but the OP didn't mention MST at all when I had posted my comment) But even 4GB is pretty large.

Comment: Does all this data need to be available at once to construct the MST? If there is such a way to write it such that it can be [parallelized](http://www.hipc.org/hipc2009/documents/HIPCSS09Papers/1569250351.pdf) (first google hit, I really have no clue), maybe something similar can be done for [resident memory] space?

Answer (score 4):

A `HashMap` will be very large, cause it will contain `Doubles` (with a capital D) which are significantly larger than 8 bytes.  (Not to mention the `Entry`)  Depends on implementation and the CPU chip, but I think it's at least 16 bytes each, and probably more?

I think you should consider keeping the primary data in a huge `double[]` (or, if you can spare some accuracy, a `float[]`).  That cuts memory usage by an easy 2x or 4x.  (500M floats is a "mere" 2GB)  Then use integer indexes into this array to implement your edges and vertices.  For example, an edge could be an int[2].  This is far from O-O, and there's some serious hand-waving here.  (and I don't understand all the nuances of what you are trying to do)

Very "old fashioned" in style, but requires a lot less memory.

Correction - I think an edge might be int[4], a vertex an int[2].  But you get the idea.  Actually, for edges and vertices, you will have a smaller number of Objects and for them you can probably use "real" Objects, Maps, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a complete graph, there is no doubt on what the edges are. How about storing the labels for those edges in a simple list which is ordered in a certain manner? So e.g. if you have 5 nodes, the weights for the edges which would be ordered as follows: `{1,2}, {1,3} {1,4} {1,5} {2,3} {2,4} {2,5} {3,4} {3,5} {4,5}`.

However, as pointed out by @BillyO'Neal this might still take up 8 GB of space. You might want to split up this list into multiple files and simultaneously maintain an index of these files suggesting where one set of weights ends in one file and where the next set of weights begin.

Additionally, given that you are finding the MST for the graph, you might want to have a look at the following paper as well: http://cvit.iiit.ac.in/papers/Vibhav09Fast.pdf. The paper seems to based off the Boruvka's Algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka's_algorithm; http://iss.ices.utexas.edu/?p=projects/galois/benchmarks/mst).

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to my adjacency matrix suggestion. But that still requires 8+GB of memory for a fully connected graph with 32768 nodes

Comment: Since I am building a minimum spanning tree from this generated graph-- is there a way I can approach this that will let me somehow build the MST as I am generating the edges? Or does that not make sense?

Comment: @quannabe this was not part of your original question. it might help to add the MST requirement/goal in the question. it will help you get better answers.

Comment: @quannabe: Both Prim's algorithm and Kruskal's algorithm (the two common ways of calculating MSTs) require building a set of all edges in the graph.